# How to loop through a field in Microsoft Access Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a table `Worklist` with two colums `Name` and `Pages`.
Now i like to print each recordset in a report as many times as the number in `Pages` but have no idea how i could loop through the `Pages` field.

**Table:**

```
--------------------
|  Name  |  Pages  |
--------------------
|  Mike  |    1    |
--------------------
|  Phil  |    3    |
--------------------
|  Lisa  |    2    |
--------------------
```

**Report Output should be:**

```
Mike
Phil
Phil
Phil
Lisa
Lisa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code that does what you want.

It loops through all lines and loops then through the number of pages.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
Private Sub loopfiles()
    Dim mydb As DAO.Database
    Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set mydb = CurrentDb
    Set Rst = mydb.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset)


    Rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not Rst.EOF
        mystring = ""
        For i = 1 To Rst![Pages]
            mystring = mystring & Rst![Name1] & " "
        Next i

        MsgBox Left(mystring, Len(mystring) - 1)



    Rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    Rst.Close


End Sub
```